# Showing all rows from a column even if count value is NULL

Tags: sql-server, database, count

I Have something like this:

CODE, ORG, TYPE, DATE are table columns.

```
SELECT     COUNT(CODE) AS OK, ORG AS ORG
FROM       EVENTS 
WHERE      (TYPE = 'A') and (DATE BETWEEN '2015-07-06' AND '2015-07-12')
GROUP BY   ORG
```

The results are:

```
OK    ORG
---------
93     1
292    2
51     3
```

The main problem is, there are a total of 6 Orgs, but they do not get listed because the COUNT have no rows to count because this week they couldn't work.

I need to always get the ORG listed, and if theres a valid COUNT value, show it, otherwise show 0. Something like this:

```
OK    ORG
---------
93     1
292    2
51     3
0      4
0      5
0      6
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a table (e.g. a table called "Organisation") where you can find all ORG-Numbers?

Comment: Yes, the table is called Organizations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch first all `ORG` from `EVENTS` and the do a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(COUNT(e.CODE), 0) AS OK,
    t.ORG AS ORG
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT ORG FROM EVENTS
)t
LEFT JOIN EVENTS e
    ON e.ORG = t.ORG
    AND e.TYPE = 'A'
    AND e.DATE BETWEEN '2015-07-06' AND '2015-07-12'
GROUP BY t.ORG
```

Comment: That works, but the OK column (COUNT) show 0 to everything,

Comment: I'm stupid, I was using an invalid column name...now it works perfect, thanks!

Comment: You can use @CeOnSql's answer. You should get the list of `ORG`s from the `ORGANIZATIONS` table.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this:

```
SELECT     O.ORG AS ORG, SUM(ISNULL(E.CODE,0,1)) AS OK 
FROM       ORGANIZATIONS O
           LEFT JOIN EVENTS E ON O.ORG = E.ORG 
                              AND E.TYPE = 'A' 
                              AND E.DATE BETWEEN '2015-07-06' AND '2015-07-12'
GROUP BY   O.ORG
```